# Reading data from Console

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, console-application

so my code displays data parsed form xml files to the console. How can I pause the Console Output box on the screen so I can read the data.

```
 var query = from file in fileEntries
                        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                        let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single()
                        let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single()
                        let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single()
                        select new
                       {

                           XMax = x.Element("Max").Value,
                           XMin = x.Element("Min").Value,
                           YMax = y.Element("Max").Value,
                           YMin = y.Element("Min").Value,
                           ZMax = z.Element("Max").Value,
                           ZMin = z.Element("Min").Value
                       };


            var results = from item in query
                          select new
                          {
            XMaxResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.XMax, double.NaN) <= 290.0 ? "pass" : "fail",
            XMinResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.XMin, double.NaN) >= -50.0 ? "pass" : "fail",
            YMaxResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.YMax, double.NaN) <= 650.0 ? "pass" : "fail",
            YMinResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.YMin, double.NaN) >= -89.0 ? "pass" : "fail",
            ZMaxResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.ZMax, double.NaN) <= 20.0 ? "pass" : "fail",
            ZMinResult = TryParseWithDefault(item.ZMin, double.NaN) >= -130.0 ? "pass" : "fail"

                          };

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("XMaxResult = {0}", result.XMaxResult);
                Console.WriteLine("XMinResult = {0}", result.XMinResult);
                Console.WriteLine("YMaxResult = {0}", result.YMaxResult);
                Console.WriteLine("YMinResult = {0}", result.YMinResult);
                Console.WriteLine("ZMaxResult = {0}", result.ZMaxResult);
                Console.WriteLine("ZMinResult = {0}", result.ZMinResult);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wait to accept a CR using:-

Console.ReadLine()

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I got question right but have you tried [Console.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx)?
It exactly stops the console output and waiting for the input.

Also there are following useful methods:

- [Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) - Reads the next character from the standard input stream
- [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx) - Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

and the program stops until you hit a key.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Console.ReadKey(true);` and it will wait for user input. So until you type something you can read the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 int count=1; 
 foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("XMaxResult = {0}", result.XMaxResult);
                Console.WriteLine("XMinResult = {0}", result.XMinResult);
                Console.WriteLine("YMaxResult = {0}", result.YMaxResult);
                Console.WriteLine("YMinResult = {0}", result.YMinResult);
                Console.WriteLine("ZMaxResult = {0}", result.ZMaxResult);
                Console.WriteLine("ZMinResult = {0}", result.ZMinResult);
               if(count%5==0)
                  Console.ReadLine();
                count++;
            }
```